# longest subsequence: missing last element

Tags: ruby, algorithm, data-structures

Hi guys I'm working on the longest subsequence algorithm, the idea is to find the subsequence of numbers from an array. I'm using Ruby, so far I'm missing the last number of the subsequence, this is my code:

```
def sequence_length1(array)
  array.sort! 
  secuencia_mayor = []
  array.each_with_index do |numero, indice|
    numero + 1 == array[indice+1] ? secuencia_mayor << numero  : ''
  end
  return secuencia_mayor
end

p sequence_length1([100, 4, 200, 1, 3, 2]) #length=4
p sequence_length1([29, 27, 28, 55, 100, 84]) #length=3
```

The code has a bug: the last element will never be part of the secuencia_mayor array due to the conditional, my question is: what should I change in the code to overcome this issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I updated this line: numero + 1 == array[indice+1] ? secuencia_mayor << numero  : numero - 1 == array[indice-1] ? secuencia_mayor << numero : ''  . Despite I obtained the needed output the execution time is too high as well as the situation to iterate twice the array; suggestions for refactoring are welcome

Comment: This code seems to sort of work - by accident. Add 2 consecutive elements to your test, say 10 and 11, and see what happens.

Comment: Another problem: `sequence_length1([29, 56, 27, 55, 84, 28]) #=> [27, 28, 55]`.

Comment: in fact, it worked by accident @steenslag, I'm in the process of understand how to program in Ruby

Comment: Does `array.sort!` invalidate the premise? I understand "subsequence" compares array elements for order; so sorting effectively "redefines" the array as passed into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the approach you have taken you need to save the longest known sequence found so far (or its starting index and length) as you loop through the elements of the array. Here is one way to do that.

```
def sequence_length1(array)
  array.sort!
  secuencia_mayor = []
  candidate = []
  array.each do |numero|
    if candidate.empty? || candidate.last + 1 == numero
      candidate << numero
    else
      secuencia_mayor = candidate.dup if candidate.size > secuencia_mayor
      candidate = []
    end
  end
  secuencia_mayor = candidate.dup if candidate.size > secuencia_mayor
  secuencia_mayor
end
```

```
sequence_length1 [100, 4, 200, 1, 3, 2]
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
sequence_length1([29, 27, 28, 55, 100, 84]) #length=3
  #=> [27, 28, 29]
```

---

Another way, which is more Ruby-like, is to use [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) and [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

```
def seq(arr)
  arr.sort.slice_when { |a,b| b != a + 1 }.max_by(&:size)
end
```

```
seq [100, 4, 200, 1, 3, 2]
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
seq [29, 27, 28, 55, 100, 84]
  #=> [27, 28, 29]
```

---

The steps are as follows.

```
arr = [100, 4, 200, 1, 3, 2]
c = arr.sort
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 200]
enum = c.slice_when { |a,b| b != a + 1 }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00007fa9fd913238>:each>
d = enum.max_by(&:size)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

We can see the (three) elements that `enum` will generate and pass to `max_by` by converting the enumerator to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [100], [200]]
```

`enum.max_by(&:size)` is shorthand for `enum.max_by { |e| e.size }`.

One can alternatively use `slice_when`'s close cousin, [Enumerable#chunk_while](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while):

```
[100, 4, 200, 1, 3, 2].sort.chunk_while { |a,b| b == a + 1 }.max_by(&:size)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed explanation @Cary Swoveland, brillian!

Comment: `enum = c.slice_when { |a,b| b != a + 1 }` is literally in the docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when

Comment: @steenslag, as does `chunk_while`. (I added a mention of that method as an alternative.)